# Windows Service Interactions

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services

I´m new to write windows services and I was searching around collecting necessery info and howtos. What I´m missing is the interaction between my webapp and the service. The servicecontroller helps me sending messages to the service and gives me the main status of the service.

Is there a way to get custom messages, set custom properties and get properties?
If there are not, should I use a file for both the service and the web app where both can read and write on, like a settings file in xml or are there better methods?

Is there a way to get the messages in the corresponding eventlog, how do i access them?

Comment: Why do you use windows service? What kind of task does it do and why does it need to be controlled by website? By answering these questions you'll give us a better understanding of your task and you'll receive better architecture recommendations.

Comment: Because there are tasks I need it for. I will get back with other questions when it´s time. Now I´m just interessted how to comunicate with a windows service. I´m now just collection some information to decide the best practice, I think there will be more question for my need, I just want them to be written, so that other people can get some good info about. It´s not all about my task, i think it is usefull for people to know the basic question "how to interact with a windows service", doesnt matter why... But thanks for you tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look into [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).  This would allow your service to "serve" information to your WebApp.

Comment: +1. I normally use WCF to communicate between Windows Services and ASP.NET. Usually, controlling the service and reading its log (`ServiceController` and `EventLog`) is not necessary from ASP.NET.

Comment: Yes, if you use WCF it´s not necessary. I just watched those videos and it is exactly what I need for now. Thanks a lot Reed!